# Can a US state declare an airplane unairworthy?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, airworthiness

(This arguably is a question for SE.Law, but because it's so aviation-specific I figured I would ask it here first)

A partner got this in a routine excise tax email from the Massachusetts Department of Revenue (MA-DOR):

> Our records indicate that your Aircraft Registration in the Commonwealth of Massachusetts is set to expire on December 31, 2023.
>
> If your Aircraft Registration has expired, as the aircraft owner, you cannot legally operate your aircraft until you receive your 2024 new registration certificate.

This got me a little curious. I could certainly see a state law which forbids locally registered aircraft from landing/taking off at state-owned airports, but I don't understand how one state can revoke airworthiness from the national airspace system. (<strike>I only have that excerpt to go off of, so don't know if a specific US or MA law was referenced.</strike> Thanks to @Chris, we have the relevant MA law: https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2017/10/30/702cmr3.pdf)

Does a US state have US-wide airworthiness authority over airplanes registered within that state?

---

#### Update

I think this question is somewhat confusing because of a widespread mistaken understanding of what "airworthy" means. As MichaelHall shows in his answer, it's definition is "the aircraft conforms to its type design and is in a condition for safe operation." Unfortunately many of us, myself included, were taught that full paperwork compliance was also required for airworthiness. This led to me using the wrong word in the question.

I'm going to keep the original question as asked, because the answers are not wrong vis-a-vis the original wording. Fixing it would do a disservice to the existing answers, and if I need further clarification about state's ability to regulate aviation outside their borders I will ask at SE.Law.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, and Massachusetts law doesn't claim to. Massachusetts only forbids you from flying in Massachusetts if you are supposed to register in Massachusetts and fail to. From 702 CMR 3.02(6):

> No person shall operate an aircraft or permit any other person to operate such aircraft within the commonwealth unless the aircraft is permitted to operate within the commonwealth pursuant to M.G.L. c. 90, § 48, 14 C.F.R. Subchapter C and 702 CMR 3.02(1) through (4).

Note that "the commonwealth" refers to Massachusetts in the text above.

Comment: Thanks! I was not going to find the CMR on my own. Not to contradict, but a lay reading of that law would seem to forbid a tax delinquent from flying in or over MA, i.e. the airplane is out of compliance with the law and is thus no longer airworthy from a regulatory perspective (which is legally just as strong as from an MX perspective). Is there a nuance in how "operate" should be understood in the above context? In the FAR, operate clearly includes "fly", and so with that same understanding of "operate" that CMR would seem to restrict said planes from being airborne over MA.

Comment: @KennSebesta I agree with your reading that the law forbids flying in or over Massachusetts. But this doesn't make the aircraft unairworthy from a Federal perspective- if you operate the aircraft in Massachusetts you are in violation of state law but not in violation of Federal law.

Comment: that's a fair point about the Federal perspective, but is that the only perspective for overall airworthiness? Or is there a "forbidden to fly but not unairworthy" clause in the FAR which would permit states to declare an airplane unfit to fly? Because from https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/77475/20394, it seems that the FAA is very clear that the states have 0 authority "to regulate any type of aircraft operations", which would be in contradiction to the CMR which regulates aircraft operations.

Comment: @KennSebesta This law, if it were applied to overflights of Massachusetts that do not land anywhere in the commonwealth is probably unconstitutional. But states and local authorities *can* regulate what happens on land. Since 702 CMR 3.02 only applies to aircraft *based* in Massachusetts it's hard to imagine a situation where it would apply to you if you never land in the commonwealth, so it may be a moot point.

Comment: It would *certainly* be unconstitutional to try to force non-based aircraft that fly over Massachusetts to register there.

Comment: Excellent point. Thanks! It sounds like the law can constitutionally apply to ground operations, and a perhaps overzealous MA-DOR representative unwittingly over-projected MA's power over the NAS.

Comment: @KennSebesta Perhaps. It's not clear that it's a real overreach since it only applies to based aircraft that spend a lot of time on land in Massachusetts. A much more blatant overreach is Massachusetts' law about [Altitude of aircraft flights](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleXIV/Chapter90/Section46)!

Comment: @KennSebesta, "Unfit to fly" and "airworthy" (or non-airworthy) are terms not mentioned in either the letter your friend received, or the law you linked to.  Registration with the state is simply an administrative requirement they have enacted to generate revenue.  You are reading more into this than is there.

Comment: @MichaelHall maybe you meant that as a comment in my post and not this answer? That aside, I'm sure you're aware that airworthy is not a "fit to fly" but a "legal to fly" determination. The upshot is I don't see how, with a plain reading, anyone is meant to understand "you cannot legally operate your aircraft" aside from a blanket, nationwide prohibition, i.e. an effective AWC revocation. What I think Chris has demonstrated is that the boilerplate in the form email is not consistent with the MA law, and it is not, in fact, a nationwide prohibition.

Comment: No, i meant to comment here, specifically because of your ongoing questioning of Chris' complete and excellent answer.  The trigger was asking whether there might be a "*forbidden to fly but not unairworthy' clause in the FAR...*".  Space here doesn't allow much more than this, perhaps i will expand my thoughts into an answer to further my point.

Comment: "*I don't see how, with a plain reading, anyone is meant to understand "you cannot legally operate your aircraft" aside from a blanket, nationwide prohibition.*" NO!  Nobody is meant to understand that any law applies outside of the jurisdiction of the legal entity that drafted the law. Putting the definition of "airworthy" aside, jurisdiction is a fundamental principal of law, and you are reading an "overreach" into this that just isn't there. Nothing in the Massachusetts law hints at applicability to owners registered outside the state.

Comment: @MichaelHall you're picking an odd fight here. When a representative of the gov't tells you something is illegal, then you're meant to understand it is illegal. Full stop, no ifs ands or buts. Now, you and I both know that representative's email is wrong, but that doesn't change how the general populace will understand it.

Comment: I'm not picking a fight, i am simply trying to get you to realize the truth of what has been presented to you. That representative's email wasn't "wrong,", it just just has nothing to do with airworthiness, and applies to Massachusetts only. I believe the general populace understands that. Please reference my answer and let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @Kenn I think a lot of the grief you're getting is because you keep using the term "airworthy" when it doesn't have anything to do with the situation. "Airworthiness" is at base a *physical* property: is the aircraft physically capable of flying safely, is it physically in compliance with its type certificate, etc. An automobile might by physically safe but illegal to drive because its registration is expired; the letter in question similarly says that the aircraft will be illegal to fly if its registration expires. That has nothing to do with whether it is "airworthy" or not.

Comment: @randomhead I think you're getting at something important here, and it might be a great demonstration of the FAA's principle of "primacy". I was taught that if the plane failed the AROW check (or any other paperwork check), that it was "not airworthy". I remember asking how an airworthiness determination was anything other than physics-based, and was told "them's the rules". https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/bought-a-new-to-me-airplane-registration-is-wrong-still-airworthy.119529/ shows that it's a common-enough viewpoint that even an IA makes the mistake.

Comment: @KennSebesta, FYI, I responded to the link above. Gosh, those old coots are worse than us!  (*awaiting moderator approval...*)

Comment: @MichaelHall lol, that's awesome. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

No.

> Does a US state have **US-wide airworthiness authority** over airplanes registered within that state?

There are two parts to this question - airworthiness and jurisdiction.

**AIRWORTHINESS:**

14 CFR, Part 3, Subpart A, § 3.5 defines the term airworthy:

> Airworthy means the aircraft conforms to its type design and is in a condition for safe operation.

The word is well defined, and has a very specific, *and limited in scope* meaning that is not applicable in this case.  In other words, it does **NOT** mean "not legal to fly due to failure to meet a state department of revenue administrative requirement".  It means only what the FAA says it means.  ...*Full stop, no ifs ands or buts.*

Neither the letter your friend received or the state law regarding registration use the term "airworthy" or any of its derivatives.  Nor does either one hint that failure to register would render the aircraft *out of compliance to its type design*, **or** *not in a condition for safe operation*.

**JURISDICTION:**

[Jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisdiction) is a foundational concept of law.  It limits the authority of a legal entity or policy making body to specific geographic borders, and/or subject matters.

The state of Massachusetts does not have "US wide authority" over aviation matters, or really any other function that occurs outside its borders.  No state does, Massachusetts does not claim or even hint that it does, and it is unreasonable to presume otherwise.

You may infer, from the letter you quoted, the following addition in bold:

> Our records indicate that your Aircraft Registration *in the Commonwealth of Massachusetts* is set to expire on December 31, 2023.
>
> If your Aircraft Registration has expired, as the aircraft owner, you cannot legally operate your aircraft **[in the Commonwealth of Massachusetts]** until you receive your 2024 new registration certificate.

(It was likely omitted in the second paragraph because it is unnecessarily redundant for the general populace.)

Comment: In other words, the answer to OP's question is "no" but only because they're asking the wrong question... they *mean* to ask "Can a US state make it illegal to operate an aircraft" which is not at all the same question as "Can a US state deem an aircraft unairworthy."

Comment: Sort of... but who are we to judge the question "wrong"?  (*Can a US state make it illegal to do something in other states is also a "wrong" question...*)  We can only answer what was asked, and in doing so perhaps point out any fallacies at the root of the question.

Comment: @MichaelHall thanks for posting the relevant FAR. That was very helpful in challenging what I was taught long ago by a CFI, which is that noncompliant paperwork equals "unairworthy".

Comment: There's a strange pedantry about answering the literal question, but not engaging with the literal source of the question. States cast power outside themselves all the time. For instance, if a driver's license is suspended by the issuing state, all other states agree to honor it. The effect is all that matters to the lay person, not the exact mechanism used. Likewise, when a MA rep says "illegal to fly" that's no different from an MA police officer saying "illegal to drive". Ignoring that with a Dukes of Hazard jump to the next county is done at the pilot's peril.

Comment: @KennSebesta, I am sensitive to pedantry and Cliff Clavinism in all forms, and I generally try to avoid it.  (Sure, if someone says "inadvertent IFR" I might quip *Oh, you accidently filed an instrument flight plan and picked up a clearance?!* but I do it with a twinkle in my eye...)  Anyway, I certainly didn't mean to beat you up on this.  Again, it isn't my definition, it is the FAA's.  Good point about possible reciprocity agreements between the states, or states and the FAA, but pretty sure the "R" in AROW requires Federal Registration, not State.  Maybe a focused follow up question?